# X11 Widget from QT QWidget

Tags: c++, linux, qt, x11

Is it possible to extract an X11/Xt Widget from QT QWidget. I know there is a function WinId() on QWidget which gives me a Window but I need a Widget object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe Qt uses Xt widgets at all, so the answer to your question would be no.

(Grepping for `Xt` in the source files found in the `src/gui/kernel` directory shows no hits.)

Answer (score 2):

No, Qt/X11 uses X11 directly (well, using xlib/xcb, no Xt) and there is no such a thing as 'X11 widget'. If you want to include Qt widget in your Xlib application, you can use [Xembed](http://standards.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/xembed-spec-latest.html) (or just reparent external qt application)